# JQuery not loading in Ios UIWebView

Tags: jquery, ios, uiwebview

I have a webView in my IOS application and I need to use JQuery. I have copied the jquery.js file inside my app, have checked the Compile Sources and have also looked under Copy Bundle Resources and my js file is being displayed only under Copy Bundle Resources.

I am accessing the html files from a server and inside the file there is the following configured:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

A function calling the following javascript works:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test';
```

A JQuery expression doesn't:

```
$('#test').html('test');
```

also `$(document).ready(function()` isn't called.

I have also tried:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jquery" ofType:@"js"];
NSData *jsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if (jsData) {
    NSString *jqueryString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:jsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jqueryString];
    NSLog(@"JQuery file loaded successfully");
}
```

The Log message is printed but still no result.

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Have you ever figured it out? I'm struggling as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax of your JQuery:

```
$('#test').text('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to user browser reachable url. Something like this, rather than using relative path.

```
<script src="http://yoursite.com/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works when I use a global URL but I need  it to also work if there is no Internet connection.